# Google Maps navigation popping up eratically

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-maps

Whenever I'm using Google Maps to navigate to a destination, Maps keeps popping up. It doesn't matter which app I'm in, Maps comes up on the screen and ALWAYS restarts (!) navigating to the last destination I specified.

Sometime it even pops up on itself, asking "do you want to stop the current navigation"

This happened about 2 weeks ago. I used to be on the beta channel for maps, but I quit that. Same with the current stable. I already tried removing the app and clear all app data, to no avail.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on my Nexus 6P.

Comment: I'm on a LG G5 stock rom

Comment: Same here with 6.0.1 (stock) on a BQ X5 Plus.